# Subscribe to Delegate with 2 int parameters

Tags: .net, uwp, observable, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm using Rx-Main (observable library) for a Windows 10 UWP project. I have an event for a third library called :

```
OnNumberChangedEventHandler

public delegate void OnNumberChangedEventHandler(int newNumber, int oldNumber);
```

I've been trying to guess how to subscrie using the

```
Observable.FromEvent<OnNumberChangedEventHandler>(x =>  x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged += x, x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged -= x)
```

But I have no how to hook to it. I know how to do it for EventHandlers, or EventDelegates with 1 parameter but in this case it has 2 int parameters. Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: It was designed to work well with the standard .NET event pattern, the one where you use `EventHandler<T>` to declare an event.  Where T would be a class that derives from EventArgs and has two extra properties, OldNumber and NewNumber.

Comment: Yes that whould be FromEventPattern, but as the event is from a 3rd library I have no control on the EventArgs, and it has 2 int parameters. I could wrap the event in a custom event but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Just a small thing - the convention in .NET is to have methods named `On*` to be the method that **raises** the event and not the **handler** of the event. I would expect your handler to be called `NumberChangedEventHandler` and the event itself `NumberChanged`. You should drop the `On`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate this syntax so much:

```
var o = Observable.FromEvent<OnNumberChangedEventHandler, Tuple<int, int>>(
    a => (i1, i2) => a(Tuple.Create(i1, i2)), 
    h => _calculator.OnNumberChanged += h,
    h => _calculator.OnNumberChanged -= h
); //o is type IObservable<Tuple<int, int>>
```

Basically, Rx needs to know how to hook/unhook to the delegate: That's the last two parameters. The first parameter is a conversion from your custom delegate to an `Action<Tuple<int, int>>`. That action is then used to OnNext the observable.

You could swap out the `Tuple<int, int>` type for something else if you so wanted.

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much, it works, I wouldn't even imagined the correct syntax. cheers! I hate the syntax so much too XD

Comment: Just as a little improvement you can use the new tuples syntax: FromEvent<OnPageNumberChangedEventHandler, (int, int)>(a => (i1, i2) => a((i1, i2))

Comment: You can simplify this down to `Observable.FromEvent<OnNumberChangedEventHandler, (int, int)>(x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged += x, x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged -= x);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Observable.FromEvent<OnNumberChangedEventHandler, (int, int)>(
    x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged += x,
    x => _calculator.OnNumberChanged -= x);
```